# How to fix the position of views in an Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have designed a layout with some views (listview, buttons etc..).
When I install my app into an Android phone, the position of views is not the same as I designed.
Some buttons are only partially visible. Can anyone please tell me how to fix the position of views in the layout?
here is the code I used to design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg4" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="3dp" android:text=" " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/Loginas"
            android:layout_width="120dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Logged in as..." android:textColor="#802A2A"
            android:textSize="18dp" android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnlgout"
            android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:background="@drawable/logout"
            android:onClick="logout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Count : 4" android:textColor="#802A2A"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Spinner android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drop" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnpreferences"
            android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:background="@drawable/pref"
            android:onClick="getPreferences" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/column1"
                android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column1" android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/column2"
                android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column2" android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/column3"
                android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column3" android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/column4"
                android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column4" android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listViewTickets"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=" " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnNew"
            android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btnnew" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
            android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:background="@drawable/edit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you paste some layout code here so that we can see how you created the UI and can suggest you.

Comment: what kind of layout? Where is the code? where is the code and efforts you have tried so far?

Comment: what are the permissions you mentioned in the manifest file...

Comment: that can only be fixed if you post code of your layout otherwise how can we know what you have done..

Comment: You should provide more information -> **Code of your Layout**

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cherry"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

// your components

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside linear layouts in views you used a constant width. It would be better if you use weight-sum for same and provide them width in by weight.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up a few layout practices like [Romain Guy's layout tricks](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/), and consider using more efficient containers than the `LinearLayout`.

You should also position your components relatively to each-other and their parent, this is the way you can achieve a proper layout that looks the same on all screens / resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Much better if you use RelativeLayout so that you can arrange the views very well.